# Drop down mvc3..wont populate the fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have got this controller:

```
    public class NewPostController : Controller
{
    List<SelectListItem> languages= new List<SelectListItem>();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["languages"] = new SelectList(languages, "Text", "Value", 1); 
        return View();
    }


    private void GetCountryList()
    {
        CultureInfo[] cultureList = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);

        foreach (CultureInfo culture in cultureList)
        {


            languages.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = culture.DisplayName,
                Value = culture.DisplayName,
              });


        }

    }

}
```

The list of items should be established by their languages and  be passed to the view.

```
            @Html.DropDownList("languages",null,
    "** Please Select **",
    new { @class = "my-select-css-class" })
```

Nothing gets populated..Why?

Comment: I don't see GetCountryList() being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GetCountryList()
```

You never call it.